# Parametros com ':'

Tags: html5, http-headers

tentei enviar um headers e tive o seguinte erro: "Invalid header name b':authority'"
E esse erro se repete para: ':method', ':path' e ':scheme'

A pergunta é, devo enviar sem o ':', ou posso ficar sem enviar esses parametros? Eu temo que os administradores do site possam identificar que minha conta deixou faltar informação no headers ou que os parametros acima foram enviados sem ':' e possam identificar que foi um bot.

Comment: Olá caro user-agent, vou logo adiantando, não tem nem sentido enviar tais parametros coisas como `:path`  e `:scheme` são gerados pelo console através do verbo e tipo de requisição para facilitar a leitura, eles não foram "enviados", ele são só uma forma de ler mais fácil e é usado só no console, não tem motivos para sair enviando algo que você nem sabe o que é, isso é programar baseado no "chute", as vezes fazemos isso, mas não faça o que não é preciso só porque viu alguém ou algo fazendo. Programe conforme a necessidade e pesquise com calma cada tipo de header.

Comment: [...] Outro detalhe caro User-Agent, http-headers não tem ligação direta com HTML5, basicamente web usa HTTP, HTML é consequencia de uma resposta, a resposta pode ser texto, pode ser video, pode ser imagem.